# show infinite sequence of tosses of a fair coin can realize any finite sequence of head and tails.

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Given a fair coin, and a finite sequence of n tosses, Show that that finite sequence will eventually be realized in an infinite tosses of coin. Explain connection with Murphy law.

I broke the infinite tosses into segments of n tosses. Consider the event $E_!$ : The first segment realizes the finite sequence of toss first, it has probability $\frac{1}{2}^n$, the probability of event $E_2$ :that the second segment realizes the finite sequence of tosses first, is $\frac{1}{2}^n (1-\frac{1}{2}^n)$. The probability of the event $e_3$: that the third segment realizes the finite sequence of tosses first, is $(1-\frac{1}{2}^n)^2 \frac{1}{2}^n$. And so on. Now probability of the event $A$: Eventually realizing the finite sequence is $\sum_i P(Ei \cap A)=\sum_i P(E_i)= \frac{1}{2}^n+ \sum_i \frac{1}{2}^n (1-\frac{1}{2}^n)^i =\frac{1}{2}^n(1+\sum_{i \geq 1} (1-\frac{1}{2}^n)^i)=1$.

This would agrees with Murphy's law that any thing that could happen will eventually happen given enough trials.

is this correct, and is there another way as I realized that we omitted a lot of length n sequences in the infinite sequence of tosses and only considered sequences that start at every n?

Comment: Not sure I understand your solution. Breaking the sequence into disjoint segments of length $n$ is a good idea. But the probability that a specific segment realizes the required sequence is always $(\frac{1}{2})^n$. Now it's very easy to use the second Borel-Cantelli lemma and get what you need.

Comment: @Mark The OP's argument is that the probability that none of the first $\ m\ $ segments realises the given sequence, but the $\ (m+1)^\mathrm{st}\ $ does is $\ \left(1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right)^m \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\ $.  Summing these probabilities gives $1$ for the probability that there is some sequence of $\ m\ $ unsuccessful segments that is followed by a a successful one.  That argument seems to me to be correct.

Comment: Oh, ok then. So OP decided to find the probability that it is the first segment which realizes the required sequence.

Comment: It seems you do not show that it will happen, but "only" that it will happen *almost surely*.

Comment: Of course. To show that it will definitely happen is absolutely impossible. We can only discuss the probability.

Comment: Sorry, what s the difference between happen and happen almost surely?

Comment: Happen almost surely means with probability $1$. You can't know what you will actually get, right? It's theoretically possible that you will keep getting heads in all tosses. It's just that the probability of this event happening is smaller than any positive number. (so it is zero)

Comment: "Almost surely" means with probability $1$.  That isn't the same thing as definitely.  If you toss a fair coin repeatedly, it's conceivable that it always lands heads, but the probability is $0$.